# How to set a variable within json_contains with raw laravel?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

by using (1) I get the wanted result from the laravel request.
But as soon as I switch the hardcoded "fish" to an variable like $str = 'fish', I get syntax errors.

```
(1) $find = animal::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, \'{"item_text": "fish"}\')')->get();
```

I already tried all kind of variations by using ' or ` or " on almost any places for example:

```
$find = animal::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, \'{'item_text': $str}\')")->get();
```

or

```
$str = 'fish'
$str2 = "\'{'item_text': $str}\'"
$find = animal::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, $str2)")->get();
```

but it does not matter what I'm trying, always syntax error or empty because the request ist looking for '$str2'.

I tried without \ `{"item_text": "fish"}`, too. Still syntax error...

What should I do to get the same result as the hardcoded example?

My setup: 
Laravel 5.8, mysql 5.7.14

Thank you very much in advance. =)

Additional Information MySQL Column animals looks like

```
[{"item_id": 1, "item_text": "fish"}, {"item_id": 6, "item_text": "birds"}]
```

Maybe there is another approach, then json_contains, to get the data by a where clause? :)

Comment: Have you tried this way `$find = animal::where(DB::Raw("JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category,?)"))->setBindings([$str2])->get();`  ?

Comment: Thank you very much but it was not the solution.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the [jsonContains()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses) method:

```
$find = animal::whereJsonContains('animal_category', ['item_text' => $fish])->get();
```

---

To answer your actual question, to get what you want you can either do:

```
whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, \'{"item_text":"' . $fish . '"}\')')
```

or

```
whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, '{\"item_text\":\"$fish\"}')")
```

However, I would strongly recommend against this as it is leaving you open to sql injection (depending on how you getting the `$fish` variable).

To get around this you can bind the value like so:

```
whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, ?)', '{"item_text":"' . $fish . '"}')
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, the last snippet is the solution.```whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category, ?)', '{"item_text":"' . $fish . '"}')``` Thank you very much. :) :) :)

Comment: @Hugo Glad I could  help!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$str2 = "\'{\"item_text\": $str}\'"
```

instead of

```
$str2 = "\'{'item_text': $str}\'"
```

JSON doesn't like the single `'` character for enclosing strings. It requires the double character: `"`.

Comment: Thank you very much @danish-khan-i and @dbalduzzi both approaches and the combination of both approaches does not work. 
I get following error msg:
Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: &quot;Invalid value.&quot; at position 0. (SQL: select * from `animals` where JSON_CONTAINS(animal_category,\&#039;{&quot;item_text&quot;: fish}\&#039;). So the same error msg as before. :/